# Recover incomplete PDF file

Tags: r, pdf, plot, pdf-generation, lsf

Considering below code, which is running on a cluster with a walltime ([#BSUB -W 10:00](https://bmi.cchmc.org/resources/software/lsf-examples)):

```
pdf("myPlots.pdf")
for(i in 1:300){
# a lot of data processing, unfortunately no data is being saved...
# ...

# then plot output
plot(1)
}
dev.off()
```

Above code exits before competing the for loop, (because of walltime) and PDF is not complete.
Then, I used [this website](https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/repair.aspx) to recover, so *plot data* is in the file, it is just incomplete.

Is there any other way to recover? Maybe add some text to PDF file (using text editor) so that PDF file is complete?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either raising the bridge or lowering the river.

That is, I would consider one of two possible revisions to your algorithm, depending on exactly what it is you're doing (for which there's not a lot of detail here, so I'm winging it): either make each iteration of your loop a complete task, in case it turns out to be the last loop before your wallclock time expires, or adjust either your loop count or wallclock limit to let the job complete more often.

If you cannot change your loop count or walltime, see if you can revise your loop process so that each iteration appends to the previous one, so that any loop ends with a complete output, and thus it doesn't matter whether there will be another iteration following.

Otherwise, either lower your loop limit to some count that will reliably complete (200 or 250, for example), or extend your walltime limit to some value that will let the task complete under a normal system load. Right now you're putting yourself between a rock and a hard place; one or the other is going to have to move.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this doesn't answer the question: is there a way to recover "incomplete" PDF? I think my question is more related to PDF standards, rather than R.